# Need help understanding this formation of a proof involving functions.

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

I'm trying to understand what exactly is going on in this example proof, but I am having trouble with the syntax of it. Here is the question, and the proof

Let $f : A\to B$ and $g : B \to C$ be functions.

Prove or disprove that if $g \circ f$ is onto, then $f$ is onto.

This statement is false, and here is a proof:

Let $A = C = \{ 1 \},$ $B = \{ 1, 2 \},$ $f = \{ (1, 2) \}$, and $g = \{(1, 1), (2,1)\}.$ Then, $g \circ f = \{(1,1)\},$ and is onto, but $f$ is not onto.

I have three main questions

1)Does $f$ mean that when you take the value $1$ from $A$, it maps to $2$ in $B$, and similarly with $g$, where $1$ and $2$ from $B$ maps to $1$ in $C$?

2) how does $g \circ f$ end up being $\{(1 , 1)\}$?

3) Why is $g \circ f$ onto, but $f$ not onto?

EDIT: By onto I mean, $\forall  b \in B, $ $\exists a \in A$ such that $f(a) = b$

Comment: For your first question, the answer is yes. For the second and third, you need to write down the definitions that you have for composition "$\circ$" and "onto" so we can relate those definitions to your example and create a better answer.

Comment: See my edits to this question for proper MathJax usage.

Answer (score 1):

1)Does f mean that when you take the value 1 from A, it maps to 2 in B, and similarly with g, where 1 and 2 from B maps to 1 in C?

Yes, f and g act as you mentioned.

2) how does g∘f end up being {(1,1)}?

$gof$  is  a function from $A$ to $C$

$$ gof(1)=g(f(1))=g(2)=1$$

3)Why is g∘f onto, but f not onto?

There is only one element $1$ in $C$ and it is covered by $gof$  thus $gof$ is onto.

$f$ is not onto because it does not cover $1$ which is in its codomain $B$

Comment: So it is because there is no $a \in A$ such that $f(a) = 1$?

Comment: Yes, because nothing is mapped onto $1$